# How to Convert from double to Int64

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a double to an Int64 and get some strange behaviors. To test my problem I tried the following code:

```
double temporary = Int64.MaxValue;
Int64 tem = Convert.ToInt64(temporary);
```

I still get an Overflow exception when converting the double to an Int64. Is this a bug? Or is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? Could the problem be the first line, and not the second?

Comment: A double can store 15 significant digits.  Int64.MaxValue has 19 digits.  So the double only contains an *approximation* of MaxValue.  It got rounded up, kaboom when you try to go back.  Never write code like this.

Comment: Couldn't have debugged this yourself?  Just look at the value in `temporary` and you'll see it's greater than the maximum value of `Int64`. The documentation for [`Convert.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325195(v=vs.71).aspx) specifically says that an overflow exception will occur. Please read the documentation next time.

Comment: @tnw the debugger removed two digits (08 was not visible) and put in scientific notation. I'm sure there are ways to configure the debugger but this was much faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crux of this is that not all real numbers can be represented by finite floating point data types. In particular, there are 64 bit integer values which do not have exact representation as double precision floating point values.

The value of [`Int64.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx) is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. The closest double precision value to this is [`9,223,372,036,854,775,808`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=9223372036854775807). So when

```
double temporary = Int64.MaxValue;
```

is executed, the value assigned to `temporary` is actually `9,223,372,036,854,775,808.0`.

When you attempt to convert this double precision value to `Int64`, an overflow occurs because the value exceeds `Int64.MaxValue`.

Comment: I am curious here. If I try `temporary = temporary - 1;` still the exception is raised.

Comment: @Steve Of course. That's because `temporary - 1 == temporary`  ;-)  Think about it.

Comment: @Steve Then try it and find out for yourself.  It would take you all of a few seconds.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the answer. The link helped a lot. I have to use 9,223,372,036,854,775,295 instead of the actual max.

Comment: Yeah, the values get pretty spaced out that far out!

Answer (score 3):

A `double` cannot exactly represent `Int64.MaxValue`, so it gets rounded up. Since a `long` can't represent the rounded-up value, you get the exception.